# JDBC: in set condition: can I pass a set as single param?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

In JDBC I can use question marks for query parameters, like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?"
```

and then

```
ps.setString(1, "vasya");
```

But how can I query for list of logins:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login IN ?"
```

suppose, I have

```
List<String> logins = ...
```

What should I type there:

```
ps.setWhat(1, what);
```

I could rewrite query as:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ? OR login = ? OR login = ?"
```

and then call setString in loop, but I'd like to know if it is possible to pass a set of elements as single param in query.

Maybe there are vendor-specific extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are vendor specific ways to do that, therefore it would be good to know what database you use. I know solutions for PostgreSQL and H2. I implemented this feature in the H2 database, so that's what I know best:

**H2 Database**

```
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
  "select * from users where login in (select * from table(x int = ?))");
prep.setObject(1, new Object[] { "1", "2" });
ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
```

**PostgreSQL**

```
WHERE login = ANY(?)
```

Then set the parameter to an array of values using PreparedStatement.setArray(..) (not setObject as for H2).

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2) for an overview of available options. As far as I can tell you, everyone is dynamically generating the necessary number of placeholder characters (with some optimizations).

There's a `setArray` method in `PreparedStatement`, but sometimes using it is not feasible. You might give it a try though.

If Spring's JDBCTemplate is an option, you could use automatic collection expansion as described [here](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/03/10/auto-expanding-collections-as-jdbc-parameters-with-spring-simplejdbctemplate/).

Comment: There is no reason that you cannot use Spring for this, and you should, as you get a real exception hierarchy for free.

Answer (score 0):

```
//---

String query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ?";    

List<Login> list = new ArrayList<Login>();      
Login login = null;

for(String param : conditions){

    pStmt.setString(1,param);

    rSet = pStmt.executeQuery();    

            if(rSet.next()){

                login = new Login();
                login.setName(rSet.getString(1));

                list.add(login);
            }
}

return list;

//---
```

conditions will be the list of item on basis of which you want to retrieve fields.

Comment: Edited my answer, might help you.

Comment: That's simply sending queries in a loop. It should be very inefficient compared to using a generated query (if the collection is reasonably large).