# Passing an array to SELECT * FROM table WHERE country IN (?...)

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there a way to pass an array of strings for a "WHERE country IN (...)" query?

something like this:

```
String[] countries = {"France", "Switzerland"};
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE country IN (?...)");
pstmt.setStringArray(1, countries);
pstmt.executeQuery();
```

an ugly workaround would be to create the query based on the size of the array

```
String[] countries = {"France", "Switzerland"};
if (countries.size() == 0) { return null; }
String query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE country IN (?";
for (int i = 1; i < countries.size; i++) { query += ", ?"; }
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
for (int i = 0; i < countries.size; i++) { pstmt.setString(1+i, countries[i]); }
pstmt.executeQuery();
```

but this looks really ugly.

any idea?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives

Comment: Some databases offer array support.

Comment: i wanted to add post but BalusC wrote everything and he wrote it awesome, so check BalusC post in thead as posted @JigarJoshi

Comment: there are vendor specific ways to do this. see this post postgresql and h2
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3724272/280393

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. ORMs like Hibernate or wrapper APIs like Spring JDBC allows doing that. But with plain JDBC, you must do it yourself.

Comment: That's not really true. Many databases support parametrized IN(...) conditions using PreparedStatements.

Comment: @jambo: It has nothing to do with databases supporting them or not. All databases do, AFAIK. But you need one placeholder per element of the IN clause.

Comment: No, that is exactly what you don't need. The exact syntax is DB specific, here for example a solution for Oracle: http://blogs.itemis.de/kloss/2009/03/05/arrays-preparedstatements-jdbc-and-oracle/

Comment: OK, so you don't need them if you create an additional type in your database, if you change your query, and if you use proprietary types. Point taken. But I would prefer generating the query by myself, keep my code database-agnostic, and my database setup simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think the work around would be formulating the entire query string at runtime and using a Statement object instead of PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

No way to try this.See [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2) to other ways.But there is one exception, if you use oracle database then you can try [this](http://blogs.itemis.de/kloss/2009/03/05/arrays-preparedstatements-jdbc-and-oracle/)

Answer (score 0):

If your database engine support IN (subquery), you can create a view or memory table to do it.